# Find if Linked list is circular

Tags: java, c++, c

Sorry to ask the basic question again but am looking for answer.
For this question why there should be fast and slow pointers iterating over the list?
Why it should not be a single pointer with logic as below

```
ptr = head->next;
while(ptr != NULL)
{
    if(ptr == head)
    {
        return true;
    }
    ptr = ptr->next;
}
return false;
```

Why can't it be this logic? All answers are based on two pointers logic is there any advantage doing that?

Comment: What about `head->node1->node2->node1->node2->...`?

Comment: "why there should be fast and slow pointers" whats a fast ptr? whats a slow ptr?

Comment: That code will always return true, since you initialize ptr to head.  But let's say you initialize it to head->next; what if the loop doesn't go back to head?

Comment: It depends on the exact problem statement.  What if there's a cycle in the list, but the element that cycles back points to, say, `head->next` or `head->head->next`?

Comment: @Borgleader, I presume one pointer moving two nodes ahead for every one the other moves ahead.

Comment: Why is this tagged `java` since this is obviously C/C++?

Comment: They move at different speeds, but determining the optimal ratio is an interesting exercise.  It's not necessarily 2:1.

Comment: There are many resources on the web that deal with this topic.

Comment: I am basically looking if linked list is circular when I referred to this site they showed one logic of fast pointer and a slow moving pointer over the list http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/data-structures/how-to-find-if-a-linked-list-is-circular-or-has-a-cycle-or-it-ends/

Comment: Sorry for wrong code I edited it, I equated it to head->next

Comment: @user2166368, Your new case fails quite simply: `head->node1->node1->...` will never be caught, nor any other loop past `head`.

Comment: @Borgleader: Imagine you have two trains, A and B, on the same track. A is in front of B and goes twice as fast. If A ever rear-ends B, then the track must contain a circle somewhere that allowed A to get behind B; conversely, if the track contains a circle then A and B cannot traverse the circle forever without a collision because A is moving twice as fast as B.  Therefore this mechanism will always determine if a track contains a cycle. The same is true of linked lists.

Comment: @EricLippert Ohhhhhh that makes a ton of sense now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to have two pointers.  For example, you can keep a list or table of pointers that you have already seen, then have a single pointer that traverses the list and consults the table to see if it has seen that already.

The advantage the two pointer solution has over the table lookup solution is you only have to allocate additional memory for two pointers, no matter how big the list is.

You cannot do one pointer and check for head, unless you're only concerned about lists that have a loop back to head.  The list could loop back somewhere in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a loop in your list not including the head, and you only have one pointer, how would you identify this? You will get stuck looping forever.
You need two pointers (or a list of previous nodes or something similar) to get around this problem.

Comment: Thanks Keppil I dint think that circular list can be looped in between. I always thought that circular list will only happen if last node next is pointing to first node.

Answer (score 0):

Here is couple ways to find a loop.

http://ostermiller.org/find_loop_singly_linked_list.html

Comment: [Link only answers aren't considered a good practice.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Answer (score 0):

```
bool circular(node head*){
    //Honestly not sure if this should be true or false...
    if(head->next == NULL) return false; 

    node ptr = head->next;

    while(ptr != NULL)
    {
        if(ptr == head)
        {
            return true;
        }
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    return false;
}
```

You do need 2 pointers... Head and ptr.

You need to keep track of where head is, and also you need another pointer to iterate through the list.

Also, with your implementation it will always will return true because `ptr == head.`

EDIT:

Reading through your link.

You also need to check if other nodes (not just head) are circular

Read through this link it breaks it down pretty well.

http://umairsaeed.com/2011/06/23/finding-the-start-of-a-loop-in-a-circular-linked-list/